# UIButton BUtton with type crashing application in iOS 8

Tags: exception, uibutton, ios8

This is a really weird bug. I had to update my Xcode to 6.0 because there was a bug only happening on iOS 8. So I recompiled and ran the application in iOS 8 to see the issue and the app crashes on any UIButton that is initialized with `[UIButton buttonWithType:]`.

Now the issue is when it stops on that line of code there is no error message displayed and if I press continue, the application loads up with no problem. Hell, I can even press the button in question and it works perfectly! Why isn't my exception displaying an error when running the app? Why would `UIButton buttonWithType]` start crashing the program?

Here's the backtrace, maybe someone can help. The line before I call the UIButton buttonWithType is just the initializer for the view:

```
frame #0: 0x381fc5d0 libc++abi.dylib`__cxa_begin_catch
frame #1: 0x3177f9ac libFontParser.dylib`TFont::CreateFontEntitiesForFile(char const*, bool, TSimpleArray<TFont*>&, bool, short, char const*) + 6784
frame #2: 0x3177d9cc libFontParser.dylib`FPFontCreateFontsWithPath + 224
frame #3: 0x2b5a62d0 libCGXType.A.dylib`create_private_data_with_path + 12
frame #4: 0x2b46bfb8 CoreGraphics`CGFontCreateFontsWithPath + 24
frame #5: 0x2b4bd4e2 CoreGraphics`CGFontCreateFontsWithURL + 310
frame #6: 0x324cdf4e GraphicsServices`AddFontsFromURLOrPath + 66
frame #7: 0x324d1a3a GraphicsServices`__Initialize_block_invoke + 934
frame #8: 0x00331ad6 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 22
frame #9: 0x00332740 libdispatch.dylib`dispatch_once_f + 100
frame #10: 0x324cd7a2 GraphicsServices`Initialize + 194
frame #11: 0x388c24d8 libobjc.A.dylib`_class_initialize + 536
frame #12: 0x388c805e libobjc.A.dylib`lookUpImpOrForward + 254
frame #13: 0x388c7f56 libobjc.A.dylib`_class_lookupMethodAndLoadCache3 + 34
frame #14: 0x388ce1d8 libobjc.A.dylib`_objc_msgSend_uncached + 24
frame #15: 0x2e720b1e UIKit`-[UIButton initWithFrame:] + 506
frame #16: 0x2e721494 UIKit`+[UIButton buttonWithType:] + 692
```

Comment: I had the same problem. Removing custom fonts fixed the problem. Afterwards I added them one by one until I found the problematic font which was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove any added custom fonts (or make sure that they exist):

1. Open your application's plist file, usually called "AppName-Info.plist".
2. Double check that the fonts listed under, "Fonts provided by application" exist. If they don't, either delete it from the plist or add it to your resources (generally, under a folder called, "AppNameResources" in your root directory.

[image]

Hope this helps!